# Why aren't aeroplanes controlled from a control center (without a pilot inside)?

Tags: flight-controls

Nowadays we have space crafts that go as far as to the Mars and they are controlled by people sitting in the earth (by some remote control method).Why are aeroplanes not controlled in this way?Are pilots absolutely necessary?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: [Your first assumption is faulty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmanned_aerial_vehicle).

Comment: Spacecraft are not subject to weather, traffic, crowding, congestion and scheduling delays.  There is no suitable alternate to re-route a spacecraft to; airplanes can be rerouted to alternate destinations.

Comment: Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Airways_Flight_1549) and you will understand and expect this will continue.

Comment: For airplanes that don't carry passengers, we already do this. In fact my country (Malaysia)'s maritime patrol fleet is being converted to drones (mostly regular planes retrofitted with long range radio control). The US is currently waging what is effectively a full-blown war/assassination program in the Middle East and Afghanistan and Pakistan using planes remotely controlled from the US. For planes that carry passengers note that even spaceships that carry passengers have pilots on board - that is a safety issue

Comment: @mins: Follow the link. The assumption that is wrong is that aeroplanes are not controlled this way

Comment: Because some of us actually enjoy flying!  IOW, commercial passenger aircraft are only a subset of all airplanes.